# Can WinLess be configured to check-out or override checked in output files?

Tags: css, tfs, less

I am trying to use winless to compile several .less and .css files to a single site.css file that is checked into source control.

Because I open and edit the .less and .css files that are checked in from within visual studio, it automatically checks them out.

However when I try to compile, the output files that are checked into source control, they are read only files when they aren't checked out, so winless throws an error.

Manually checking out the output files or removing the read-only flags solves the issue, but I'd prefer it if it could happen automatically.

Answer doesn't necessarily need to be the approach that I'm trying right now. If any of you handle less output files in a different way that avoids this issue, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using TFS 2012+ you can use a Local (instead of Server) workspace, and it won't set files as read-only anymore (and it will auto-detect any changes).